# Can I pass variables to PHP GD imagefilter?

Tags: php, gd, imagefilter

I know the `imagefilter` function expects a long but is there a way to cast a variable to a long or am I forced to simply create separate functions for each filter. My thought is this:

```
public function ImgFilter($filter, $arg1=null, $arg2=null){
    $this->lazyLoad();
    if($this->_cache_skip) return;
    if(isset($this->_image_resource)){
        imagefilter($this->_image_resource, $filter);
    }
}
```

It's complaining about my `$filter` variable. For this example my `$filter` value is: `IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE`

Is this possible?

Comment: You are passing `"IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE"` as **string**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided:

```
$filter = "IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE"
```

You should be able to use the function [constant](http://php.net/constant):

```
imagefilter($this->_image_resource, constant($filter));
```

However note that the following will also work just fine:

```
$filter = IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE
imagefilter($this->_image_resource, $filter);
```

You can pass around the constant as an argument without a problem if you need to do so. The former is only useful if you really need the constant name to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is made this way:

```
<holder> = (<type>) <expression>

$var = (int) "123";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function would do what you need:

```
public function ImgFilter($filter, $arguments = array())
{
    $this->lazyLoad();

    if ($this->_cache_skip) {
        return;
    }

    if (isset($this->_image_resource)) {
        $params = array($this->_image_resource, $filter);

        if (!empty($arguments)) {
            $params = array_merge($params, $arguments);
        }

        call_user_func_array('imagefilter', $params);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$this->ImgFilter(IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
$this->ImgFilter(IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, array(0, 255, 0));
```